# how many tables do i need to create in MYSQL

Tags: database-design

can anyone tell me or help me with this please how many tables would i need to create in MYSQL?

Comment: Millions. Millions and millions...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't know what your boss wants from you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly are you looking for.

But there is no limit to the number of DB you can create.  Refer to the below link if you are looking for the limitations.
 [Number of Databases and Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/database-count-limit.html)